# Fixed-size Eigen matrices in CppAD

Tags: c++, eigen, autodiff, fixed-size-types

If I try to run the following code in CppAD using eigen:

```
  Eigen::Matrix<CppAD::AD<double>, Eigen::Dynamic, 1> position(3);
  CppAD::Independent(position);
```

This runs fine.  However, if I try to execute:

```
  Eigen::Matrix<CppAD::AD<double>, 3, 1> position;
  CppAD::Independent(position);
```

The following assertion is raised:

```
cppad-20180000.0 error from a known source:
default construtor result does not have size zero
Error detected by false result for
    d.size() == 0
at line 143 in the file 
    /usr/include/cppad/utility/check_simple_vector.hpp
cpp_adgen_tests: /usr/include/cppad/utility/error_handler.hpp:206: static void CppAD::ErrorHandler::Default(bool, int, const char*, const char*, const char*): Assertion `false' failed.
```

How can I use fixed (non-Dynamic) sized Eigen vectors in CppAD?

Comment: For what it's worth, I have a solution that's fine for now - I create a Dynamic vector, and then extract it to a fixed size vector using segment, and then work with that.  I will leave this open in case anyone has a non-workaround solution.

Comment: Looks like an internal design issue of CppAD to me. You may try `Eigen::Matrix<CppAD::AD<double>, Eigen::Dynamic, 1, 0, 3, 1>` (the latter `3` means `MaxRowsAtCompileTime` -- that way at least no additional memory allocation will be necessary to store the data. I'd still consider this a workaround though.